# What are non-contentious scenarios when using new(...)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

From the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.9.0) for Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9:

> There is now a refactoring that suggests using new(…) in non-contentious scenarios.

What are non-contentious vs contentious scenarios?

Comment: I dont know, is it `List<int> x;`

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/47996 .

Comment: @JeroenMostert nice find. So the first blurb sums this up "*Only appears in scenarios where the type is obvious from syntax. i.e. field declarations. **Will not appear in cases where the existing 'var' preference would prefer that be 'var' instead.***" i.e. where it wouldn't prefer `var`... You should answer this up.

Comment: Can you add an answer indeed, preferably with two examples (non-contentious vs contentious)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) for finding the the original feature request

[Add new feature to suggest using 'new(...)' in non-contentious scenarios](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/47996)

> Only appears in scenarios where the type is obvious from syntax. i.e.
> field declarations. Will not appear in cases where the existing 'var'
> preference would prefer that be 'var' instead.

Basically the feature is saying, it will give you suggestions when `var` is not preferred in the context.

**Contentious Example**

```
List<string> bob = new List<String>();
```

In the above case it will prefer to suggest `var`

```
var bob = new List<String>();
```

**Non-contentious Example**

```
public class Bob
{
    List<string> _bob = new List<String>();
}
```

In the above case `var` cannot be used, so it would suggest `new()`. This is because the contextual keyword `var` may only appear within a local variable declaration.

```
public class Bob
{
    List<string> _bob = new();
}
```

**Another non-contentious Example**

```
var derp = new List<Bob>()
   {
      new Bob(),
      new Bob(),
      new Bob(),
   }
```

The above would be a valid place to suggest `new()`

```
var derp = new List<Bob>()
   {
      new(),
      new(),
      new(),
   }
```

<sub>*Note to Jeroen Mostert, if you answer I'll remove this post.*</sub>

Comment: Excellent, maybe help future readers by clarifying this:

In the above case var cannot be used, so it would suggest new(). This is since the contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration.

Comment: Should be obvious but if you've told VS to not use `var` ever (e.g. editorconfig), you'll also get recommendations for `new()` in contentious scenarios.